# Expanding the Magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A magnetic field $B$ can apply a force $X$ on a ferromagnet when there is no gap to separate them, $r$ = 0.
When that gap ($r$) is increased to 3 cm, the force drops to zero. 
How can that be solved? How can I expand the magnetic field so that it can be applied over larger distances? What methods are known to solve such a problem?

Comment: http://www.technologyreview.com/view/514201/physicists-build-worlds-first-magnetic-hose-for-transmitting-magnetic-fields/

Comment: This technology is a remarkable advancement. Maybe it could narrow down and concentrate the magnetic field possibly? Thank you for sharing.